# Do local variables in webassembly live in the same stack?

Tags: memory, stack, virtual-machine, webassembly, allocation

I know that webassembly is a stack-based virtual machine (or that it is bytecode run on such a machine). This means that instructions like `(i32.const)` or `(i32.load)` push values onto the stack and instructions like `(i32.add)` or  will pop values from the stack to use. However, does that mean that local variables made with:

```
(local $var i32)
```

inside of a function automatically reserve space in the stack? Or is that only true for "executable" instructions? Wouldn't it be possible to pop the stack local variable that way? Also how would the amount of the stack to pop be determined when returning from a function call?

I realize that local variables have their own instructions like `(local.set)` and `(local.get)`, so it feels like they live on a different stack than the one where temporary data from executable instructions live.

Answer (score 0):

How one will implement the WebAssembly runtime is not strictly defined by the specification. What is defined is the outcome of the execution.

Some instructions can trap in certain cases. These cases are defined by the specification. For a module to be valid, the local get/set instructions indexes (or names) must be valid in their current scopes. That means that during runtime [these](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/instructions.html#variable-instructions) instructions must not trap because the indexes/names they reference are invalid.

That means that the runtime environment must allocate the needed stack space for all locals during the call of the function. The implementation [may have limitations](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/implementation.html?highlight=implementation%20limitations#execution) on the frames/values in the stack. There are discussions about the [maximum evaluation stack depth](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1163). From the specs:

> If the runtime limits of an implementation are exceeded during execution of a computation, then it may terminate that computation and report an embedder-specific error to the invoking code.

Additionally to that the stack in WebAssembly is polymorphic and at  runtime a valid program must not be able to pop more then it has pushed. However, during validation it is possible, [cite](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/algorithm.html):

> However, a polymorphic stack cannot underflow, but instead generates Unknown types as needed.